# Why do I get a TS2345 error when I try to run angular 2 quickstart in Visual Studio 2015 SP3?

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2015

I am new to Angular, TypeScript, and Angular 2.  I can get the Angular 2 quickstart example to work in the command line tools, but I am struggling to get it to work in Visual Studio 2015.  I see that there are a number of posts with issues similar to mine as it sounds like a duplicate, but I could not find any that exactly solve my issue.  The quick start instructions I have tried to follow are at [Angular 2 Quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/visual-studio-2015.html.)
In the project file, I have specified TypeScipt 2.0 as shown here:
[image]
In the Windows command line i type tsc -v and it reports back Version 2.2.1.

I type npm -v and I get 4.4.1.

[image: Solution Structure]

When I build, I get the following following error in my output.

ild started: Project: Angular2E, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>C:\Users\rpeterson\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Angular2E\Angular2E\e2e\app.e2e-spec.ts(12,57): error TS2345: Build:Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Expected>'.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

When I open the app.e23-spect.ts file that I pulled from the github repository,

I get
    import { browser, element, by } from 'protractor';

```
describe('QuickStart E2E Tests', function () {

let expectedMsg = 'Hello Angular';

beforeEach(function () {
    browser.get('');
});

it('should display: ' + expectedMsg, function () {
    expect(element(by.css('h1')).getText()).toEqual(expectedMsg);
});

});
```

I do not understand what a TS2345 error really means, except it seems to be something related to the TypeScript.

I do not know if it is significant or helpful, but Visual Studio 2015 SP3, does give some squiggle lines on "describe","beforeEach", "it", "expect" and when I mouse overthem, I get "Cannot find name describe", etc.

I checked the installed Nuget packages and Typescript.compiler v2.0.0. is installed.

These are the references in my project.
[image]

Am I missing a package?  Have I got the project configured wrong.  Any insight or suggestions would be greatly appreciated, because I honestly don't know where to go from here.

Comment: My tsc version is currently 2.2.1.

Comment: I think I might have partially solved this problem by installing TypeScript tools for Visual Studio 2015 from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=48593.  Now, the TS2345 error gives me. Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error  Build:Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Expected<Promise<string>>'. Angular2E C:\Users\rpeterson\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Angular2E\Angular2E\e2e\app.e2e-spec.ts 13

Answer (score 2):

I am pleased to share that I have successfully got the Angular 2 Quickstart project to build and run in Visual Studio 2015 SP 3.  So, to review, I checked my tsc version in the Windows command line with tsc -v to find I had Version 2.2.1.  I checked my node version on the command line with npm -v to find my npm version was 4.4.1.  The first part of the fix was that I had to install an updated version of TypeScript Tools for Visual Studio 2015 SP 3.  This seems to have remedied most of the typescript build errors.  The final build error was fixed by editing the app.e2e-spec.ts file that came with the Angular 2 Quickstart project.  Note that when I tested this project in Node it worked.  The line that did not seem to work in Visual studio was

```
expect(element(by.css('h1')).getText()).toEqual(expectedMsg);
```

I had to change this line to

```
expect<any>(element(by.css('h1')).getText()).toEqual(expectedMsg);
```

I admit I am still a little unclear on the reasons, but this did the trick.